# Can you inject dependencies into a constructor of a custom WebViewPage, using an IOC container?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In MVC 3, I understand you can create custom WebViewPages.  Can you inject dependencies, using constructor injection, via an IOC container?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an expample for view injection in a blog post by Brad Wilson http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt3-views.html

The statements of the others that views allow constructor injection not entirely correct. Yes `IDependencyResolver` enables creating views that have constructor arguments. But unless you are implementing your own view engine this won't help you at all. Existing view engines like razor will require that you have a parameterless constructor. This means you can do only property injection on views with them.

But as the others said you shouldn't do view injection anyway. Your view should be dumb and just render the view model to HTML. Anything requiring a dependency should be done in the controller or a service.

Comment: What if you have custom authorization that you want to be able to use as a property of the view? (to specify certain parts that shouldn't be rendered in razor without the required permissions)

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to perform *constructor* injection. But you can do something like this with, say, Ninject:

```
    public abstract class CustomViewBase<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
    {
        [Inject]
        public IFace Face
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

And assuming you have set up IDependencyResolver in Global.asax you should correctly have the @Face property initialised. **But** one important caveat: you may not access @Face in _Layout.cshtml, because (according to Brad Wilson) Layout works outside MVC, and @Face will be null when you try to access it in the layout page.

In any case I agree with the others in that the view should not have to deal with any complex logic.

Comment: THIS is awesome! I didn't realize you could do that with Ninject.

Comment: Doesn't have to be Ninject either.  Autofac and others will do the same thing, without needing the decorator.

Comment: It worked well in inherited pages. But what is the solution for accessing same injected class methods inside layout (masterpage) in MVC

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible, but i really think it is not a good idea. Why would you need some "services" on the view level ? Remember the key MVC guideline - **a view must be dumb.** In fact, it should be just some sort of template for transformation of view model object to HTML, nothing more.

Comment: Good point. He should be injecting services into the `Controller`, not the view.

Comment: i18n translations within the view. View contains the keys and you simply pull the right translation. No reason why that can't be in the view.

Comment: What about a localization or configuration type service that just contain text? They're technically still dumb