# Simple Injector - Custom WebViewPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I've a small application (for now) that uses translations.
My translation Service is called Translator (ITranslator).

My problem is that I don't want to retrieve this class in every controller (which returns a view) so I may use it in my views.

I've a similar problem with a ListService (where I store all my `SelectListItem` lists).

**CustomWebViewPage**

```
public abstract class CustomViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    readonly IScriptFactory scriptFactory;
    readonly IMembership membership;
    readonly IListService listService;
    readonly ITranslator translator;

    IHtmlString path;

    public IMembership Membership { get { return this.membership; } }
    public override IPrincipal User { get { return this.membership.User; } }
    public IListService Lists { get { return this.listService; } }
    public ITranslator Translator { get { return this.translator; } }

    public CustomViewPage(IScriptFactory scriptFactory, IMembership membership,
        IListService listService, ITranslator translator)
    {
        this.scriptFactory = scriptFactory;
        this.membership = membership;
        this.listService = listService;
        this.translator = translator;
    }

    public IHtmlString OwnScriptsPath
    {
        get { return path ?? (path = scriptFactory.Create(this.Html).ToHtmlString()); }
    }

    private string languageHtml =
        "<meta name=\"language\" content=\"" + membership.CurrentLanguage + "\">";
    public IHtmlString MetaLanguage { get { return MvcHtmlString.Create(languageHtml); } }
}
```

and the usage:

```
<div>
   @Lists.GetNationalities(Model.NationalityId)
</div>
```

However, when running the application I've the following error:

> '[NAMESPACE].CustomViewPage' does not contain a constructor
>   that takes 0 arguments

But if I create a second constructor, Simple-Injector will throw an error since it doesn't support multiple constructors.

How may I achieve what I want, or isn't it possible?

**Edit**

Full stack trace

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\520dfaa2\f5e4578c\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.jtlk7fxz.0.cs(40):
>   error CS1729: 'SportsHub.SDK.Infrastructure.CustomViewPage'
>   does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

```
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

**Edit 2**

As @StriplingWarrior and @Steven suggested, I used property injection, however it doesn't seem to be working on `WebViewPage`

I tested it on a service and Property Injection was successful, but in this class, the property comes `null`.

PS: I made the properties public with get;set;

New ViewPage:

```
public abstract class CustomViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    [Inject]
    public IScriptFactory scriptFactory { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public IMembership membership { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public IListService listService { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public ITranslator translator { get; set; }

    IHtmlString scriptsPath;
    public IHtmlString OwnScriptsPath()
    {
        if (scriptsPath == null)
        {
            scriptsPath = scriptFactory.Create(this.Html).ToHtmlString();
        }
        return scriptsPath;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Renders the current user language with a meta tag
    /// </summary>
    public IHtmlString MetaLanguage()
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<meta name=\"language\" content=\"" + membership.CurrentLanguage + "\">");
    }
```

For the `InjectAttribute` I've followed the following [documents](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-property-injection-behavior).

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656195/can-you-inject-dependencies-into-a-constructor-of-a-custom-webviewpage-using-an

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I've seen those examples with injection attributes. However simple-injector doesn't provide them

Comment: Please provide us with the complete stack trace of the exception you are getting.

Comment: @LeandroSoares: Can you not define a binding for SimpleInjector that uses a default constructor and then initializes those properties?

Comment: @Steven stacktrace added

Comment: @StriplingWarrior maybe, but if the creator of simple-injector didn't implemented it for some reason. In last resort I'll try to implement it

Comment: You can do property injection with Simple Injector: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-property-injection-behavior

Comment: What I don't understand though is how Simple Injector is involved in this. The exception shows that the type is being created by ASP.NET; not by Simple Injector. If this is the case, where does Simple Injector come in? Do you sometimes resolve the type from Simple Injector as well? And if so, why do you have two different methods of resolving?

Comment: @Steven, the problem isn't Simple Injector itself, I was trying to figure if I could override the default behavior with Simple Injector. I was trying to figure out if I could inject properties inside WebPageView since I didn't know that property injection was possible.

Comment: But this doesn't really help when Simple Injector isn't in control of the creation of the type.

Comment: Well maybe I didn't use the right words. But I wanted something like that. Simple Injector controlling the creation of this types

Comment: @Steven, I implemented property injection, see the edited post

Comment: @Steven: That's a good question. ASP.NET MVC is actually invoking Simple Injector (via `IDependencyResolver`) to create the object, but the View compilation still requires the type to have a default constructor. According to [this article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt3-views.html), "The reason is a fairly technical one that has to do with the way the ASP.NET page compilation system works when it's converting your markup into a class."

Comment: @LeandroSoares: Can you show all the important pieces of code? Registration of the InjectAttribute, for example? Also, you're not trying to access this dependency from `_Layout.cshtml` are you?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, indeed I'm. Why? :s

Comment: @LeandroSoares: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7690878/120955) says, "But one important caveat: you may not access `@[PropertyName]` in _Layout.cshtml, because (according to Brad Wilson) Layout works outside MVC, and `@[PropertyName]` will be null when you try to access it in the layout page."

Comment: You are right, damn... Ok, it works now, I just moved that language method that was being called on the layout to a static class.
May I ask you or @Steven for an answer so i just accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a register dependency container like [this](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html). That's way, you can specify all the interfaces and what is the matching implementation when the ASP.NET will call that SimpleInject to resolve the dependency.

You can also create a parameterless constructor like this:

```
public CustomViewPage() : base(new ScriptFactory(), new Membership()...) { }
```

But I wouldn't recommend that... that best thing it's to have this dependency resolution logic working.