# SimpleInjector and custom WebViewPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simple-injector

I have a custom `WebViewPage`, and I would like SimpleInjector to resolve some dependencies in it. It seems like I can't use constructor injection due to the way MVC instantiates this class.

I've enabled explicity property injection as described in the [SimpleInjector documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-property-injection-behavior). But the properties are not getting injected - they're always `null`.

custom WebViewPage class:

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
   [Import]
   public IMyDependency Dependency { get; set; }

   public void UseDependency()
   {
      Dependency.DoStuff(); // Dependency is null
   }
}
```

IOC setup:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new ImportPropertySelectionBehavior();

container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

container.Register<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

Do I need to wire anything else up to get this working? I've tried registering the custom WebViewPage with SimpleInjector (mapping `WebViewPage<>` to `CustomWebViewPage<>` and making my class non-abstract), but that didn't work either.

Just to be clear, all other property and constructor dependency injection is working in the application - just not for this particular class.

Comment: There's this related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704650 - but this is about using something from the custom WebViewPage class in a view. This bit is fine for me, but not the property injection.

Comment: If I am not understood wrongly - are you saying MVC doesn't allow constructor injection???(because I inject dependencies of controllers via constructor only)

Comment: `It seems like I can't use constructor injection due to the way MVC instantiates this class` that's odd. Did you had a look at this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925290/dependencyresolver-setresolver-not-working

Comment: @Rudresha - yes of course MVC allows for constructor injection, I use it in all my controllers. But it doesn't seem to work in a custom WebViewPage class. It's very possible I'm doing something wrong though.

Comment: @Stefan I got that from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/7656195/77090

Comment: Ahh.. sorry, my bad...

Comment: Have you considered this remark: `But as the others said you shouldn't do view injection anyway. Your view should be dumb and just render the view model to HTML. Anything requiring a dependency should be done in the controller or a service.`?

Comment: @Stefan yes, that's definitely an important point. I'm doing this to replicate some functionality in a related project. For some reason some partials may error, so I wanted a method to try to render the partial, catch the exception and log it. The logger is injected. There's arguments to be had about why the partials might error, but for now, here I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Remo Gloor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681173/264697) and the statement from Stefan:

> But as the others said you shouldn't do view injection anyway. Your view should be dumb and just render the view model to HTML. Anything requiring a dependency should be done in the controller or a service.

That said, in case you really, really, really need this (which you shouldn't), I think it's a matter of creating a custom `IViewEngine`.

**WARNING: The code below is NOT!!! tested AT ALL***

```
internal class PropertyInjectionViewEngineDecorator : IViewEngine
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Registration> registrations = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Registration>();

    private readonly IViewEngine decoratee;
    private readonly Func<Type, Registration> createRegistration;

    public PropertyInjectionViewEngineDecorator(IViewEngine decoratee, Container container)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.createRegistration = type => Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(type, container);
    }

    public ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext context, string partialViewName, bool useCache) =>
        this.InitializeView(this.decoratee.FindPartialView(context, partialViewName, useCache));

    public ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache) =>
        this.InitializeView(this.decoratee.FindView(context, viewName, masterName, useCache));

    public void ReleaseView(ControllerContext controllerContext, IView view) =>
        this.decoratee.ReleaseView(controllerContext, view);

    private ViewEngineResult InitializeView(ViewEngineResult result)
    {
        if (result.View != null)
        {
            Registration registration = this.registrations.GetOrAdd(result.View.GetType(), this.createRegistration);
            registration.InitializeInstance(result.View);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You can hook this custom `PropertyInjectionViewEngineDecorator` into the MVC pipeline as follows:

```
var razor = ViewEngines.Engines.Single(e => e.GetType() == typeof(RazorViewEngine));
ViewEngines.Engines.Remove(razor);
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new PropertyInjectionViewEngineDecorator(razor, container));
```